# Class Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager does not exist

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

hi guys so im working in some symfony project and this error still display to me i have changed the Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager to Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface; and still not working
please i need some help it's for my university exams i tried alot to fix this issues even i look it up to stackoerflow about a solution but i didn't find anything can help

```
    <?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use App\Entity\Article;
use App\Repository\ArticleRepository;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
class BlogController extends AbstractController
{
/**
 * @Route("/blog", name="blog")
 */
public function index(ArticleRepository $repo): Response
{
   // $repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Article::class);
    $articles = $repo->findAll();

    return $this->render('blog/index.html.twig', [
        'controller_name' => 'BlogController',
        'articles' => $articles
    ]);
}
/**
 * @Route("/",name="home")
 */
public function home(){
    return $this->render("blog/home.html.twig",[
        "title"=> "miral",
        "age" => 31
    ]);
}

   /**
 * @Route("/blog/new", name="blog_create")
 */
public function create(Request $request, ObjectManager $manager){
    dump($request);
    if($request->request->count() > 0){
        $article = new Article();
        $article->setTitle($request->request->get('title'))
        ->setContent($request->request->get('content'))
        ->setImage($request->request->get('image'));
        $manager->persist($article);
        $manager->flush();
    }
    return $this->render("blog/create.html.twig");

}

/**
 * @Route("/blog/{id}",name="blog_show")
 */
//ArticleRepository $repo, $id
public function show(Article $article){
    //$repo=$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Article::class);
   // $article= $repo->find($id);
    return $this->render("blog/show.html.twig",[
        'article' => $article
    ]);
}

}
```

Comment: Try `composer dump-autoload` in console

Comment: nah it didn't work sir

Comment: Start by running: `bin/console debug:container EntityManagerInterface` just to verify you have a service.  If no service exists then you have something seriously wrong with your doctrine.yaml configuration.  Assuming the service exists then update your create method to inject it.  I know you said you already tried it but but you probably had typos or something of that nature.  If you still get an error then update your question with the exact error message.

Comment: i don't know what happen when i want to work with forms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most likely need to use `Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectManager` instead of `Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager` which has been removed in newer versions of Doctrine. However, there is no alias for that class (you can check that with `bin/console debug:autowiring doctrine`) so I guess the easiest way would be to use `Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface`.

Try this.

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use App\Entity\Article;
use App\Repository\ArticleRepository;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class BlogController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/blog", name="blog")
     */
    public function index(ArticleRepository $repo): Response
    {
        $articles = $repo->findAll();

        return $this->render('blog/index.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'BlogController',
            'articles'        => $articles
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/",name="home")
     */
    public function home()
    {
        return $this->render("blog/home.html.twig", [
            "title" => "miral",
            "age"   => 31
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/blog/new", name="blog_create")
     */
    public function create(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $manager)
    {
        if ($request->request->count() > 0) {
            $article = new Article();
            $article->setTitle($request->request->get('title'))
                ->setContent($request->request->get('content'))
                ->setImage($request->request->get('image'))
            ;
            $manager->persist($article);
            $manager->flush();
        }

        return $this->render("blog/create.html.twig");

    }

    /**
     * @Route("/blog/{id}",name="blog_show")
     */
    public function show(Article $article)
    {
        return $this->render("blog/show.html.twig", [
            'article' => $article
        ]);
    }

}
```

Comment: thaaankkkkkkkkkk you alooooooooooot

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, here is the new path :

```
use Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectManager;
```

Answer (score -1):

There are no classes related to persistence in the `Doctrine\Common` namespace. So you have to use i.e. [Doctrine\DBAL](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal).

Comment: please sir tell me how to fix it what should i change ?

Comment: @David - ObjectManager is actually an interface which is implemented by the EntityManager.  You could indeed add it as an aliases to the Symfony container and inject it.  You sometimes see this when a developer really wants to avoid being directly dependent on the ORM namespace.  Unfortunately the original poster does not seem to be actually reading the responses.

Comment: @Cerad thats evil obfuscating, I wouldn't advise that

Comment: @David I know this is not the best place for these sorts of discussions but you might want to actually take a look at the ObjectManager interface.  Perhaps you might change your mind.  As it stands, your answer is just plain wrong.